# Java to C# code converter

Tags: c#, java

Are there any converters available that converts Java code to C#?

I need to convert the below code into C#

```
String token = new String(""); 
URL url1 =new URL( "http", domain, Integer.valueOf(portnum), "/Workplace/setCredentials?op=getUserToken&userId="+username+"&password="+password +"&verify=true"); 
URLConnection conn1=url1.openConnection(); 
((HttpURLConnection)conn1).setRequestMethod("POST"); 
InputStream contentFileUrlStream = conn1.getInputStream(); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contentFileUrlStream)); 
token=br.readLine(); 

String encodedAPIToken = URLEncoder.encode(token); 
String doubleEncodedAPIToken ="ut=" + encodedAPIToken;//.substring(0, encodedAPIToken.length()-1); 
//String doubleEncodedAPIToken ="ut=" + URLEncoder.encode(encodedAPIToken); 
//String userToken = "ut=" + URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8"); //URLEncoder.encode(token); 
String vsId = "vsId=" + URLEncoder.encode(docId.substring(5, docId.length()), "UTF-8"); 
url="http://" + domain + ":" + portnum + "/Workplace/getContent?objectStoreName=RMROS&objectType=document&" + vsId + "&" +doubleEncodedAPIToken; 
String vsId = "vsId=" + URLEncoder.encode(docId.substring(5, docId.length()), "UTF-8"); 
url="http://" + domain + ":" + portnum + "/Workplace/getContent?objectStoreName=RMROS&objectType=document&" + vsId + "&" +doubleEncodedAPIToken;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below links might help:

1. [Microsoft Launches Java-to-C# Converter](http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/977781/Microsoft-Launches-Java-to-C-Converter.htm);
2. [Tangible Software Solutions inc.](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The code is not very complicated, but if you don't have the time to translate it, you can use a tool like [JLCA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=46bea47e-d47f-4349-9b4f-904b0a973174&displaylang=en)(Java Language Conversion Assistant 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can try [VaryCode](https://www.varycode.com/converter.html)</s> *Domain no longer exists and no valid snapshots in the Wayback Machine*

But you used classes like URLEncoder, BufferedReader etc. that are hard to convert to C# without losing some Java-specific features. For this particular part of code it is insignificant but in prospect you can get some unpredicted behavior of the whole converted program.